# Google Protocol Buffers doesn't set value in builder

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have an abstract class, in which a Google Protocol Buffers message is being created using abstract methods just like in the following code example:

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageCreator {

    private long queryId;

    protected AbstractMessageCreator(long queryId) {
        this.queryId = queryId;
    }

    protected void createMessage() {
        SomeMessage.Builder messageBuilder = SomeMessage.newBuilder();

        messageBuilder.setId(queryId);
        messageBuilder.setSource(getSource());
        messageBuilder.setDestination(getDestination());

        System.out.println(messageBuilder);
        System.out.println("Details:");
        System.out.println(queryId);
        System.out.println(getSource());
        System.out.println(getDestination());

        // the above lines are written to the console, the following one just prints null           
        System.out.println(messageBuilder.build().getSource().getSomeProperty());

        // doing something with the created message
    }

    protected abstract SomeSource getSource();
    protected abstract SomeDestination getDestination();
}
```

When I create a concrete class using this one as its superclass and try to create my message, its values don't get initialized, although all of the return values are written to the console, which means that the methods are providing some values, which can not be set in the builder.

Do you have any ideas what's causing this? I am using Protocol Buffers 3.5.1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is missing code here. Where does queryId and queryBuilder come from?

Comment: Hi @Jorgeblom, it was a copy-paste error, I just corrected it. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Can you include the protobuf message object? What are `SomeSource` and `SomeDestination`?